# make a dictonary on python from a list that has lists in it

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i have created a list that has lists in it;

```
[['2020/10/07', 'AA123', '19.24', '22.00'],
 ['2020/11/17', 'BBB123', '23.59', '00.00'],
 ['2020/14/67', 'AAA123', '08.00', '16.00']]
```

Problem 1: However I'm unsure on how to turn this list into a dictionary. I've tried several times and nothing works for me. I want the second value in each list(index 1) to be the key for the dictionary and the rest to be values.

Problem 2: If the second element in each list exists in more than one list, I want them to be found under the same key.

Comment: "I want the second value in each list(index 1) to be the key for the dictionary and the rest to be values." Can you write code that takes one of these lists and produces the appropriate key? Can you write code that takes one of these lists and produces the appropriate value? Can you write code that takes the keys and values and produces a dict? What code did you try to write? What happened when you used it? How was that different from what you want?

Comment: "If the second element in each list exists in more than one list, I want them to be found under the same key." What is "them"? Can you show an example of input data that has these matching data, and show exactly what the resulting dict should be?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
my_dict = {}
for sub_list in vals:
    val_key = sub_list[1]
    if val_key in my_dict:
        my_dict[val_key].extend([sub_list[0]] + sub_list[2:])
    else:
        my_dict[val_key] = [sub_list[0]] + sub_list[2:]
```

1. Create an empty dictionary to place your values into.
2. Go through all entries in your data.
3. Key the key for that entry (`sub_list[1]`), we'll use this to index our dictionary.
4. If that key already exists, extend the value stored at that list with this item's non `[1]` values (e.g. `['a', 'b', 'c']` becomes `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` for example).
5. If that key doesn't exist, just create a new key in the dictionary with the non `[1]` values.

Answer (score 1):

You can first extract the keys and values from you first list using list comprehension:

```
keys = [row[1] for row in l]
values = [[row[0], row[2],row[3]] for row in l]
```

And then create the dictionnary using the same technique:

```
{k:v for k,v in zip(keys,values)}
```

(the `zip` function allows to iterate over the 2 lists keys and values simultaneously)

For Problem 2: unfortunately you can't have the same key multiple times in a dictionnary, you may have to use `len(keys) == len(set(keys))` to test if your keys list have duplicates (the `set` function extracts all unique values from the list).

Answer (score 0):

```
raw = [
#     <date>      <key>     <val1>   <val2>
  ['2020/10/07', 'AAA123', '19.24', '22.00'],
  ['2020/11/17', 'BBB123', '23.59', '00.00'],
  ['2020/14/67', 'AAA123', '08.00', '16.00'],
]
```

(edited your example slightly to have a duplicate key)

It sounds like you want your output to be something like this:

```
{key: [info, ...], ...}
```

we can do this as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict, namedtuple
Data = namedtuple('Data', ('date', 'val1', 'val2'))
res = defaultdict(list)
for date, key, val1, val2 in raw:
    data = Data(date, val1, val2)
    res[key].append(data)
res = dict(res)  # Strip defaultdict behavior
```

then we can see

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(res)
```

gives us a result similar to that desired:

```
{'AAA123': [Data(date='2020/10/07', val1='19.24', val2='22.00'),
            Data(date='2020/14/67', val1='08.00', val2='16.00')],
 'BBB123': [Data(date='2020/11/17', val1='23.59', val2='00.00')]}
```